# Research on evaluating the performance of cache-obliviousness in practice

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computer-architecture, reference-request, cpu-cache

[Cache-oblivious algorithms and data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm) are a rather new thing, introduced by Frigo et al. in [Cache-oblivious algorithms, 1999](http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS395T/2009fa/papers/coAlgorithms.pdf). Prokop's [thesis](http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupertech.csail.mit.edu%2Fpapers%2FProkop99.pdf&ei=Dc1tT-aLI8bm4QSC4YjAAg&usg=AFQjCNHWhtzqOQqUonQWHduna8_nbQYx2g&sig2=Nf_YDGY3NZLj7q0FY6TZgw) from the same year introduces the early ideas as well.

The paper by Frigo et al. present some experimental results showing the potential of the theory and of the cache-oblivious algorithms and data structures. Many cache-oblivious data structures are based on static search trees. Methods of storing and navigating these trees have been developed quite a bit, perhaps most notably by Bender et al. and also by Brodal et al. Demaine gives a nice [overview](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~imunro/cs840/DemaineCache.pdf).

The experimental work of investigating the cache behaviour in practice was done at least by Ladner et al. in [A Comparison of Cache Aware and Cache Oblivious Static Search Trees Using Program Instrumentation, 2002](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~ccm/cs34/papers/ladnerbst.pdf). Ladner et al. benchmarked the cache behaviour of algorithms solving the binary search problem, using the classic algorithm, cache-oblivious algorithm and cache-aware algorithm. Each algorithm was benchmarked with both implicit and explicit navigation methods. In addition to this, the thesis by [Rønn, 2003](http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/frederik/thesis.pdf) analyzed the same algorithms to quite high detail and also performed even more thorough testing of the same algorithms as Ladner et al.

**My question is**

> Has there been any newer research on *benchmarking* the cache behaviour of cache-oblivious algorithms in *practice* since? I'm especially interested in the performance of the static search trees, but I would also be happy with any other cache-oblivious algorithms and data structures.

Comment: [a related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/190/41) about the appropriate tags for the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already covered background research on cache-oblivious algorithms quite well. In terms of benchmarking and practical results, I see this recent paper by Intel as an interesting read:

[A Synergetic Approach to Throughput Computing on x86-based Multicore Desktops](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/papers/tpt_ieee.pdf)